# Pmie_logger and pmlogger daily both fail to start

Tags: 20.04, systemd, services

I've tried enabling and restarting both services but they continually fail, even on reboot.

```
The job identifier is 110800.
Oct 12 19:14:36 [server] pcp[2555877]: pmie_daily failed - see /var/log/pcp/pmie/pmie_daily.log
Oct 12 19:14:36 [server] systemd[1]: pmie_daily.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
-- Subject: Unit process exited
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
```

led to

```
pmie_daily: Error: no pmie instance running for host "local:"
[/etc/pcp/pmie/control.d/local:5] ... inference engine for host "local:" unchanged
```

which led to

```
$version=1.1

# local primary inference engine
#Host           P?  S?  Directory                                 Arguments
LOCALHOSTNAME   y   n   PCP_LOG_DIR/pmie/LOCALHOSTNAME/pmie.log   -c config.default
```

and

```
Directory 'PCP_LOG_DIR/pmie/LOCALHOSTNAME' does not exist
```

Same thing for pmlogger_daily

```
-- The unit pmlogger_daily.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 12 19:22:59 [server] systemd[1]: Failed to start Process archive logs.
-- Subject: A start job for unit pmlogger_daily.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Read the messages. Follow the directions given in the error messages. Look at the log file, execute the suggested commands.

Comment: May be u had changed your hostname.
If so, you must restart pmie. systemctl restart pmie && systemctl restart pmie_daily

Answer (score 0):

Found this on 1832262 – pmie_daily.service runs as pcp but tries to do root things :

> Andreas Waschinski 2023-06-08 01:16:00 UTC
>
> (In reply to Nathan Scott from comment #14) > Hmm, thanks - can you
> say which specifically file it was in that directory, > owned as root?
> Sure, today it was: pmie.log.20230607 Previously, on May 31 to be
> exact, I even had the last two rotated log files owned by root:
>
> -rw-r–r–. 1 pcp pcp 100 31. Mai 11:13 pmie.log
> -rw-r–r–. 1 pcp pcp 158 30. Mai 00:08 pmie.log.20230529
> -rw-r–r–. 1 root root 380 30. Mai 14:48 pmie.log.20230530
> -rw-r–r–. 1 root root 194 31. Mai 11:13 pmie.log.20230531

They are aware (whoever "they" are)...